# ClassCircularityError with grails 2.1 in debug mode

Tags: grails, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

Since upgrading an app from grails 1.3.7 to 2.1.0 I am getting the error below when attempting to submit(post) forms.

It only happens in debug mode though!

I'm using Groovy/Grails Tool Suite 3.1.0

```
5:41:13 ERROR [GrailsExceptionResolver] ClassCircularityError occurred when processing request: [POST] /myapp/contextRoot/addItem - parameters:
startTimeDate: 
addcoupon: Add Item
maxRedemptions: 
timeZone: Europe/London
termsAndConditions: 
percentOff: 
title: test
buyX: 
discountType: 
shortDescription: 
redemptionType.id: 
getY: 
categoryKey: 
amountOff: 
org/springframework/beans/PropertyBatchUpdateException. Stacktrace follows:
org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.exceptions.ControllerExecutionException: Executing action [addItem] of controller [com.mastercard.deals.merchant.testController]  caused exception: Runtime error executing action
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.exceptions.ControllerExecutionException: Runtime error executing action
    ... 3 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    ... 3 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCircularityError: org/springframework/beans/PropertyBatchUpdateException
    ... 3 more
```

I'm baffled as to why this is happening...any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the [following](http://jira.grails.org/browse/GPSPRINGSECURITYOPENID-19) JIRA appears similar to the issue:

I now run the app with -noreloading argument in debug mode and it works:

```
-grails-debug -noreloading -Dserver.port=8082 run-app
```

Comment: Warning: This then disables class reloading which means you need to restart grails to see any changes.

Comment: Correct - Shoud have added that.